# Moving an object randomly on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I want to move an object randomly on keypress (spacebar to be specific). However, I am new to JS. I couldn't achieve complete randomness. Can somebody help me in this code to achieve that? And also, when I press the spacebar the image is bigger, but when I use mouse the image becomes smaller. I want the image to be small always.

Edit 1 : To achieve randomness, I have used some absolute value. so there is a range within which the randomness works. I want to remove the dependency on absolute value.

when I use mouse up, down events, the image becomes smaller.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {}
    
    canvas {
      border: 1px;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $(function() {


      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      };
      img.src = "http://www.earthtimes.org/newsimage/eating-apples-extended-lifespan-test-animals-10-per-cent_183.jpg";

      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
      var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
      var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
      var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
      var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
      var isDragging = false;


function handleMouseDown(e){
  canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // set the drag flag
  isDragging=true;
    }

function handleMouseUp(e){
  canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // clear the drag flag
  isDragging=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // user has left the canvas, so clear the drag flag
   //isDragging=false;
}

      function handleMouseMove(e) {
        canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
        // if the drag flag is set, clear the canvas and draw the image
        if (isDragging) {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
          ctx.drawImage(img, canMouseX - 128 / 2, canMouseY - 120 / 2, 128, 120);
        }
      }

      function handleKeyPress(e) {

        if (e.which == 32) {
          canKeybX = Math.random() * 500 * Math.random();
          canKeybY = Math.random() * 400 * Math.random();
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
          ctx.drawImage(img, canKeybX, canKeybY);
        }

      }
      

      $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
      $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});
      $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
      $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
        handleMouseMove(e);
      });
      $("#canvas").keydown((function(e) {
        handleKeyPress(e);
      }));

    }); // end $(function(){});
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=1300 height=800 tabindex='1'></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't see the image getting bigger? The code seems to work. What exactly is not working?

Comment: I updated your jQuery reference to use a CDN, and placed the code in a snippet. As you can see, it works fine. Please edit your question to include details of why you believe this code does not do what you require.

Comment: edited with my observation

Comment: Now I have added the code for mouse movement. Please check now, there is changes in the size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this edition works for me. Add `imgWidth` `imgHeight` vars, instead of numerical values, add width and height to each canvas redraw, and fixed positioning of img on keypress.

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
      <style>
        body {}
        
        canvas {
          border: 1px;
        }
    
      </style>
    
      <script>
        $(function() {
    
          var imgWidth = 128;
          var imgHeight = 120;
    
          var img = new Image();
          img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
          };
          img.src = "http://www.earthtimes.org/newsimage/eating-apples-extended-lifespan-test-animals-10-per-cent_183.jpg";
          var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
          var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
          var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
          var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
          var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
          var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
          var isDragging = false;
    
    
    function handleMouseDown(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      // set the drag flag
      isDragging=true;
        }
    
    function handleMouseUp(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      // clear the drag flag
      isDragging=false;
    }
    
    function handleMouseOut(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      // user has left the canvas, so clear the drag flag
       //isDragging=false;
    }
    
          function handleMouseMove(e) {
            canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
            // if the drag flag is set, clear the canvas and draw the image
            if (isDragging) {
              ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
              ctx.drawImage(img, canMouseX - (imgWidth / 2), canMouseY - (imgHeight / 2), imgWidth, imgHeight);
            }
          }
    
          function handleKeyPress(e) {
    
            if (e.which == 32) {
              canKeybX =  (canvasWidth-imgWidth) * Math.random();
              canKeybY = (canvasHeight-imgHeight) * Math.random();
              ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
              ctx.drawImage(img, canKeybX, canKeybY, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            }
    
          }
          
    
          $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
          $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});
          $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
          $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
            handleMouseMove(e);
          });
          $("#canvas").keydown((function(e) {
            handleKeyPress(e);
          }));
    
        }); // end $(function(){});
      </script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <canvas id="canvas" width=1300 height=800 tabindex='1'></canvas>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!, however, the image is bigger when I use spacebar, but when I use mouse it is smaller

Comment: Thanx Max... however,  I have a doubt. If I press the mouse and then keyboard, it works fine. However, If I use the keyboard at first, it doesn't seem to work. why so? and how to fix this?

Comment: It works as intended. But as with any other element on the page, you should first focus it, and then it will react. So when you click canvas first, you automatically focus it, so any consecutive keypress works, but if you want canvas to react to keypress initially, you have to focus it programmatically:  `$("#canvas").focus();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want this you have to set your `128, 120` always on draw. Your just setting this width and height on mouse move. Maybe you should make the width and height dependend on the screen size of your user with something like `window.innerWidth`

```js
var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 128, 120);
      };
      img.src = "http://www.earthtimes.org/newsimage/eating-apples-extended-lifespan-test-animals-10-per-cent_183.jpg";

      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
      var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
      var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
      var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
      var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
      var isDragging = false;


function handleMouseDown(e){
  canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // set the drag flag
  isDragging=true;
    }

function handleMouseUp(e){
  canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // clear the drag flag
  isDragging=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
  // user has left the canvas, so clear the drag flag
   //isDragging=false;
}

      function handleMouseMove(e) {
        canMouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
        canMouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
        // if the drag flag is set, clear the canvas and draw the image
        if (isDragging) {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
          ctx.drawImage(img, canMouseX - 128 / 2, canMouseY - 120 / 2, 128, 120);
        }
      }

      function handleKeyPress(e) {

        if (e.which == 32) {
          canKeybX = Math.random() * 500 * Math.random();
          canKeybY = Math.random() * 400 * Math.random();
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
          ctx.drawImage(img, canKeybX, canKeybY, 128, 120);
        }

      }
      

      $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
      $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});
      $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
      $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
        handleMouseMove(e);
      });
      $("#canvas").keydown((function(e) {
        handleKeyPress(e);
      }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=1300 height=800 tabindex='1'></canvas>
```